# JIRA Gadget Multiselect field select all

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I've created a JIRA gadget that has a multiselect field which by default (isConfigured == "false") has no field selected. Is it possible to have the default, when the gadget is first added to the dashboard that multiselect items are selected?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. Apply these changes to your *gadget.xml* file:

```
...
<UserPref name="projectId" display_name="Project" datatype="select" default_value="My def value"/>
          ...
          fields: [
              {
                userpref: "projectId",
                label: "Project",
                type: "select",
                selected: this.getPref("projectId"),
                options: projects
              },
          ...
```

More code you can find here: [JIRA - list projects in configuration and remember selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440194/jira-list-projects-in-configuration-and-remember-selection/24695154#24695154)